# Is there way to wrap string with single quotes in Prepared statement setString()?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have this column in a MySQL table which has a JSON string and I'm trying to pull records using regex.
For example, the column 'paylod' (datatype long text) holds this value

```
{
"type":"assignment",
"location":"12345"
}
```

I'm using RLIKE to fetch records based on location.

```
select * from table where payload RLIKE '"location":"[[:<:]]12345[[:>:]]"';
```

When using this query in java, I'm using prepared statement.

```
String pattern = "\"location\":\"[[:<:]]12345[[:>:]]\""
```

And when I use `preparedStatement.setString(payload, pattern)`, I'm not getting any results back. But when I execute the query in workbench, I see the rows fetched.

I'm guessing it's because I'm using setString, it is wrapping pattern with double quotes and MySQL is not able to parse it.

So is there a way forward? My requirement is to get records based on key-value pair in the JSOn payload column.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, adding escape character in string helped.

```
String pattern = "'\"location'\":'\"[[:<:]]12345[[:>:]]'\"";

String patternValue = pattern.replaceAll("'","\\\\");
```

So the string becomes `\"location\":\"[[:<:]]12345[[:>:]]\"` where \ serves as escape character for " in mysql, when string is wrapped inside ""

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the driver to me. Consider reporting it to MySQL/Oracle. BTW: Why are you using replace here? You could just insert the backslashes yourself immediately in the string.

Comment: If I insert backslahes in string, doesn't Java treat them as string escape character?

Comment: How else would your second string in replaceAll work? If you want a single backslash in a string **literal**, you need to use two backslashes (one signals an escape, and the second signals it needs to produce a backslash). As an aside, in `replaceAll`, you need 4 backslashes to produce a single backslash given how a regex replacement works.